# Unable to move forward with a openquery function because of the server connection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using an openquery function and I have been stuck with this error message :

**Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]**

**OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11"** for linked server "MSSQLSERVER01" returned message "Login timeout expired".

**OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11"** for linked server "MSSQLSERVER01" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".

Here is the code:

```
        Select* Into #PTBV  

        From Openquery(MSSQLSERVER01,'exec tempdb.dbo.dynamicPTBV') 

        GO
```

[image]

Comment: Is the Named Pipes protocol enabled?

Comment: Look at the update.. It was enabled